Is redis in Python asynchronous?
I have the following Python code:
import redis

from app.infra.services.notifications import INotifier
from app.schemas.notification import NotificationMessage
from app.config import settings


REDIS_CLIENT_PUBSUB = redis.StrictRedis(
    host=settings.REDIS_HOST,
    port=settings.REDIS_PORT,
    password=settings.REDIS_PASSWORD,
)

class RedisNotifier(INotifier):
    def __init__(self):
        self.redis_client = REDIS_CLIENT_PUBSUB

    async def send_notification(self, room: str, notification: NotificationMessage) -> None:
        await self.redis_client.publish(room, notification.json())


redis_notifier = RedisNotifier()

I have a web application written in FastAPI that will use redis_notifier to post messages to channels. My question is if it really:
self.redis_client.publish(room, notification.json())
It is asynchronous, that is, my web application will be able to abandon this coroutine and do other things while publish is finished?
I'm a little confused with the redis and aioredis library, I don't know if my code makes sense or I'm doing something wrong

Redis here is synchronous which means it blocks the execution your code till it completes the operation.
You may use aioredis.  or   asyncio-redis
https://aioredis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
https://pypi.org/project/asyncio-redis/

I read something that now aioredis is part of the Redis library, do you know anything about this?

YES, definitely asyncio-redis is the way (and it is integrated into the redis library)

aioredis last release is 2.0.1 and dates back to December 2021. aioredis was merged into redis-py 4.2.0rc1+, so it is possible to get it with a standard installation of redis-py.
Find examples here
https://redis-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/asyncio_examples.html

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
